# Wordpress - wp-config.php does not exist

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that when i try to connect to the url, it directs me to `site-url/wp-admin/setup-config.php` and when I navigate to public_html, the wp-config.php file is no where to be found.

I have to add that there are some `installer*.php` files added to `public_html`.

What do I have to do to connect to the website without redirecting to `setup-config.php` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get redirected to `site-url/wp-admin/setup-config.php` when wordpress cannot find `wp-config.php` file in you site root directory.

you can create `wp-config.php` manually from the sample file which comes with standard wordpress. Its named `wp-config-sample.php`. Just rename it to `wp-config.php` and 
edit following lines to reflect your database settings:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

more details about `wp-config.php` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

If you don't have `wp-config-sample.php` file you can get the file from latest wordpress archive [here](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip)